# Setting a select option default to a previously set option

Tags: php, html, sql, drop-down-menu, modal-dialog

In my modal window, I have a select where a user can select a breakfast meal from my database. By selecting a meal and submitting it, a record is saved in the database. However, I would like to achieve that when the user enters into the same modal window, whatever meal they have selected before hand will appear as the default option. I have created a query that checks to see if a meal has already been selected (optionquery1). Any ideas to achieve this? Thanks

On a side note, I'm not sure that I'm setting the date php variable currently. The day, month and year is stored in the html hidden inputs but not sure how to extract the values.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<div class="modal-body">
  <form action="my_planner.php" method="post">
  <!--<span class="test5"></span>-->
  <!--<span class="test"><input type="text" name="id_disabled" value="" disabled/>-->
  <input class="test" type="text" name="id1" value="" style="text-align:center; border:0px; font-weight:bold; font-size: 25px;"/>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="month" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="year" value=""/>

<br>
<p id="breakfastTag"><br>Breakfast:</p>
<select id="breakfast" name="breakfast">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select your breakast</option>
<?
$meal='breakfast';
$date='<input type="hidden" name="id" value=""/>'.'<input type="hidden" name="month" value=""/>'.'<input type="hidden" name="year" value=""/>';
$query = $db->prepare("select * from recipe_category where categoryID=1");
$query->execute();

while ($results = $query->fetch()) {
    $recipeID=$results["recipeID"];
    $query3 = $db->prepare("select * from recipe where id=:recipeID");
    $dbParams3=array('recipeID'=>$recipeID);
    $query3->execute($dbParams3);
    $breakfast = $query3->fetchAll();

    $optionquery = $db->prepare("select * from user_planner where userID=:userID and date=:date and meal=:meal");
    $optionParams= array ('userID'=>$thisUser, 'date'=>$date,'meal'=>$meal);
    $optionquery->execute($optionParams);

    while ($results12 = $optionquery->fetch()) {
        $selectedmeal = $results12['recipeID'];
    }

    $optionquery1 = $db->prepare("select * from recipe where id=:recipeID");
    $optionParams1= array ('recipeID'=>$selectedmeal);
    $optionquery1->execute($optionParams1);

    while ($results123 = $optionquery1->fetch()) {
        $selectedrecipe = $results123['name'];
    }

    foreach($breakfast as $breakfast): ?>
        <option  value="<?= $breakfast['id']; ?>"><?= $breakfast['name']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach;} ?>
</select>
```

Comment: compare your data with database value using ternary operator...

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, you need to use the `selected` attribute on the `<option>` you want to show.
First remove the `selected` attribute from the first `<option>`:

```
<option value="" disabled>Select your breakast</option>
```

Then in the `foreach` loop you need an `if` condition:

```
$results123 = $optionquery1->fetch();
$selectedrecipe = $results123['id'];

foreach($breakfast as $breakfast): ?>
    <option  value="<?= $breakfast['id']; ?>" <?php if ($breakfast['id'] == $selectedrecipe) echo 'selected' ?>><?= $breakfast['name']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach;} ?>
```

Notice I have removed the `while` loop since we are sure Mysql will return only one record (`WHERE ID = <ID>`).

Comment: Thanks! If a breakfast hasn't been set, how do I make the default answer 'Select a breakfast' that is disabled?

Comment: Hi, with HTML, if no `<option>` contains a `selected` attribute, the default case that you mention, the first `<option>` (containing 'Select a breakfast') will be chosen by the browser.

Comment: The first breakfast in the db is being displaced when no breakfast has been set. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Hmm, don't get it.